# WCF working in Visual Studio but Failing Open underlying provider in IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008, iis-7.5

I have a RESTFul project in Visual Studio that works fine in the Visual Studio development localhost, but that fails when I access it directly on IIS 7.5. I can see fine the .svc info, but accessing the method I get the error:

```
The underlying provider failed on Open
```

With all these details:

```
en System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
en System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
en System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
en System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
en System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() en System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) en Service.GetBooksList() en c:\inetpub\wwwroot\JsonTestApp\App_Code\Service.cs:línea 18 en SyncInvokeGetBooksList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

I have been browsing long and everybody talks about the connection string, but as far as I know is OK, specially since it works fine in Visual Studio. This is my connection string that connects a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="modelEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.Model.csdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HP-HP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=test_android;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Can someone, please, help me? Being a newbie in this, is a painful beginning...

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why the &quot is getting in there. I would replace &quot;  with ". It should be connection string="data source...". Never mind, it looks like ef is adding metadata tags encapsulating the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the connection string below on your development deployment app.

```
<add name="modelEntities" connectionString="Server=HP-HP\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test_android;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I get the message 'Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode. To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity Framework connection string is specified in the config file of executing application. To use these classes, that were generated from Database First or Model First, with Code First add any additional configuration using attributes or the DbModelBuilder API and then remove the code that throws this exception.

Comment: EF is using a specialized connection string read by the EF. I incorrectly assumed the meta-data would be independent of the connection string. Here is a thought. If you have time to experiment. Add a clean connection string as above and apply it in the EF constructor I am sure there is somewhere in the context or unit of work where you can set a plain connection string.